# How to write a middleware to optimize postgres for incoming messages per second

Tags: node.js, postgresql

In my company, we have an ingestion service written in Go whose job is to take messages from a HTTP end point and store them in Postgres. It receives a peak throughput of 50,000 messages/second. However, our database can handle a maximum of 30,000 messages/second.

Is it possible to write a middleware to optimize this? If so please explain.

Comment: No middleware will increase the throughput of your database server.

Comment: What do you mean by "middleware"? And why is this question tagged with [tag:node.js] instead of [tag:go]?

Comment: Why is 30,000 the limit?  How do you know that that is the limit?

Comment: We just need to design some kind of a data structure without using database sharding or any other message queueing technology, it's just a question I am asked in an interview, I need to find an answer